# Excel VBA macro code for pasting columns data in a single column

Tags: vba, excel

[image: pasting multiple columns under single]

there are multiple columns more than 3

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 loops and loop by row then column storing each value into a 1D array which can be written out in one go to a target column. Faster to assign in one go than writing to sheet during loop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ReArrange()
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long, arr(), arr2(), counter As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        arr = .Range("C2:E4").Value '<== Assume data is in this range
        ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr, 1) * UBound(arr, 2))
        For iRow = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            For iCol = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                counter = counter + 1
                arr2(counter) = arr(iRow, iCol)
            Next
        Next
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arr2), 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr2)
    End With
End Sub
```